# How to test an if statement with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, while-loop

I currently have no way of testing the if statement of this code, but the refresh part works.

This is the piece of code that I am not sure how I could swap the elements from the webpage to have a working if statement:

```
while True:
if any(["Auto Notify" in h1.text.replace("ADD TO CART") for h1 in driver.find_elements_by_link_text("ADD TO CART")]):
    break

else:
    sleep(random.uniform(8.0, 9.9))
    driver.refresh()
    sleep(random.uniform(1.0, 2.0))
```

This is what I have done in order to make an if statement that refreshes the page constantly at a random rate, the randomized sleeping feature is working but I am not sure about the if statement that I have injected the elements with.

Comment: @Arcane Monarch bump

Comment: Comments are not bumping posts here

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are a few spaces missing on the if statement:

```
while True:
    if any(["Auto Notify" in h1.text for h1 in driver.find_elements_by_link_text("ADD TO CART")]):
        break

    sleep(random.uniform(8.0, 9.9))
    driver.refresh()
    sleep(random.uniform(1.0, 2.0))
```